# Trying to iterate through images & change src url within a div ID using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop, src

Trying to iterate through all the images in a DIV class and change them out according to the landscape/portrait mode which detects from a function im not sure why it isnt working

```
   for(var i = 0; i < $('#imgChange').children().length; i++){
        var img = $('#imgChange').children[i];
        // deviceOrientation - imageDimensions
        // portrait-landscape, portrait-portrait, landscape-portrait, landscape-landscape
        // img.children[i].attr('src','image' + i + '-' + orientationCheck() + '.png');

        img.children[0].attr('src','image' + i + '-' + orientationCheck() + '.png');


    }

}
```

Testing the first image. The rest havent been changed out yet

```
 <div class="content" id="imgChange" custom-bg="1542111504805.png" >
 <img src="image0-portrait.png"/>
 </div>
 </div><div class="slide">
 <div class="content" id="imgChange" custom-bg="1542111396159.png" >
 <img src="1542110991156.png"/>
  </div>
  </div><div class="slide">
 <div class="content" id="imgChange" custom-bg="1542106085955.png" >
 <img src="1542110993877.png"/>
 </div>
 </div><div class="slide">
  <div class="content" custom-bg="1542106179480.png" >
 <img src="1542110996555.png">
  </div>
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate ids, use class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is going into `children` twice, and the actual image is only one level deep. Also as @Ahmed Hammad points out, you can't have duplicate `id` values on your elements - use a class instead.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('.imgChange').length; i++){
  var img = $('.imgChange')[i];
  // deviceOrientation - imageDimensions
  // portrait-landscape, portrait-portrait, landscape-portrait, landscape-landscape
  // img.children[i].attr('src','image' + i + '-' + orientationCheck() + '.png');

  $(img.children[0]).attr('src','image' + i + '-' + orientationCheck() + '.png');
}
```

Comment: `img.children[0]` is not a jQuery object

Comment: console log `img`, what is it? BTW you need to change "id" to "class" in your html

Comment: `img` is a dom element and so is `img.children[0]` and dom elements don't have an `attr()` method...that is a jQuery method

Comment: oh I see your point, I though it was the OP. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way to write this is using `attr(attributeName, function)`.

Assumes you replace the duplicate id's and change to class instead

```
$('.imgChange img').attr('src', function(_,i){
     return 'image' + i + '-' + orientationCheck() + '.png'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Jquery. Remember ID attribute values should be unique. You must not use `id="imgChange"` more than once. Try this:

```js
let imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.imgChange img')
for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
    img = imgs[i];    
    img.src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ea55d4ade339de113b9720c933546564?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"
    //img.attr('src','image' + i + '-' + orientationCheck() + '.png');
}
```

```css
.imgChange{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgChange">
  <img/>
<div/>


<div class="imgChange">
  <img/>
<div/>
```